# Is there synchronous loading in threejs?

Tags: javascript, three.js, synchronous

I have a scene stored in a `scene.json` file (created in threejs editor). I would like to load the scene in javascript synchronously, ie. something like:

```js
const scene = some_function("scene.json");
scene.add(camera);
renderer.render(scene, camera);
```

I only found how to do it asynchronously by:

```js
loader.load("scene.json", function(scene){
  scene.add(camera);
  renderer.render( scene, camera );
});
```

but I don't like it, as I'll have a sizable logic after loading the scene, and on the other hand the scene itself is small and won't affect page loading times.

Comment: There is no synchronous loading of resources in browsers, at all. Why would you want to do that?

Comment: how about use async await instead of callback?